# Restrict App Engine access to G Suite accounts on custom domain

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

A while ago App Engine-related settings for Google Apps (which is now called G Suite) domains, have been moved to the Google Cloud Console.

As of now, the documented way to restrict access to an App Engine instance to users of the associated G Suite is through this Google Cloud Console page:

[image]

When you click on [Edit] in that page, under "Google authentication" you can switch between "Google Accounts API" and "Google Apps domain" (which should actually be called "G Suite domain").

[image]

There is an input box below that dropdown, but no explanation what should be input there. Through trial-and-error I have found that it's supposed to be the domain name of the associated G Suite.

In a minimal Hello World app deployed to App Engine, we set the authentication option to:

```
login: required
```

Please note that some services of our app are written in Python, others in Java.

Accessing the App engine instance through the [project-id].appspot.com hostname works just fine, Google will prompt for credentials on the associated G Suite, and redirect appropriately through the authentication process to the target pathname.

The problem is that authentication does not work, at all, when accessing the App Engine instance through a custom domain. This will show a 500, and the server log reads:

> Authentication for the Google Apps domain example.com can only be performed when requests are served from a subdomain of that domain or it has been approved through the Google Apps Control Panel. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth

The linked page in that error message does not exist anymore, i.e. it has been replaced with a page that describes authentication in general. Lifting that old page from online caches, I can see that it described the old Google Apps way of adding the App Engine project to the Google Apps services page, but as of now this functionality has been removed, or migrated to Google Cloud Console.

For what it's worth, Google support could not offer any assistance beyond pointing me at documentation of the screenshoted pages above.

Is there anyone here who managed to restrict App Engine access to G Suite accounts through a custom domain? Or is this feature just broken?

In particular I'm looking for answers that solve this in the context of Python and/or Java GAE apps, and for code that demonstrate how to solve this programmatically if needed.

Comment: Was the service producing that particular 500 error written in python or java?

Comment: The particular service where we encountered the bug was written in Python, but if it turns out that restricting access to G Suite accounts is only possible for Java apps, we'll migrate. Hence the broad scope of the question.

Comment: It's not clear from the screenshots, but do you also have the G Suite domain listed under 'Custom domains', and are you making the request to the app through the the custom domain, rather than the appspot.com domain?

Comment: Yes to both, and I mention this in the text, actually.

Comment: Does this authentication work only with Standard GAE where I can set `login`field in handler? I would like to use this mechanism in Flexible GAE but currently it does not work. My page is widely open for all.

Comment: Haven't tried it in flexible, but perhaps your question should be a separate topic to attract solutions.

Comment: I have it already on [How to restrict access to GAE Flexible site only for GSuite account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611869/how-to-restrict-access-to-gae-flexible-site-only-for-gsuite-account).

Answer (score 5):

It appears this is a known issue with Google Apps Domain authentication, where the authentication does not work if you enable Google Apps Domain authentication *after* the domain is added to the 'Custom domains' section of the console.

The workaround is to remove the custom domain mapping from 'Custom domains', and then re-add it after enabling Google Apps Domain authentication for the domain. The documentation page [Using Custom Domains and SSL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl) will be updated to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks, it appears that fixed it! Just tested with our dev instance, server error is gone, and the constraint to the hosted domain works. A remaining cosmetical issue is that Google's auth will prompt for credentials against our domain, but will accept username/password for a non-hd account, and only after completing authentication it will redirect to the username prompt. I guess that's because Google can't detect where the account is until after the auth dance, correct?

Comment: I'm not actually clear on what is happening based on your description. This might be better posted as a new question so you can provide screen shots for context.