# How to restrict access to GAE Flexible site only for GSuite account?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

How to restrict access to GAE Flexible site only for all account from my domain in GSuite and eventually other Google accounts that I provide explicitely. AFAIR there where something simillar in Standard GAE version in `app.yaml` handlers section.

So my scenario:

- prodution versions restricted until go-live
- dev and stage version restricted permanently

I would like to do this on the IAM level, to reject traffic to the site. But I didn't found anything in docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after rethink the problem and dig deeper in a documentation I found a page about dev environment - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-separate-dev-environments.

So my current solution is not to have separate versions like `dev`, `stage` and `prod` and work with them within one project, but to create separate projects for each of environment.

It will also simplify management of DBs - previous I thought about different database in one DB server for particular environment. Now I will have a separate DB instance for it.

Anyway I still have a problem with securing access.
I did it in the same way like in [Restrict App Engine access to G Suite accounts on custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943712/restrict-app-engine-access-to-g-suite-accounts-on-custom-domain):

- changed Google Authentication to my Google Suite domain
- added Custom Domain in my app
- added my page domain to my GSuite as a second domain
  And I still can connect to my page without auth - even in "Incognito mode" and on others computers and mobiles.

**EDIT:**
As a workaround I used [Django-lockdown](https://github.com/Dunedan/django-lockdown) module. For the timebeing is more than enough - I have a password, I have a session, I can set it in Middleware or as a decorator for urls.

**EDIT 2:**
I noticed today a new feature in GAE Flexible - [Identity-Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/).
This is the feature, that I was searching. You can restrict accces by:

- Google Account email: user@gmail.com
- Google Group: admins@googlegroups.com
- Service account: server@example.gserviceaccount.com
- Google Apps domain: example.com